# How to resolve memory issues with xarray.concat

Tags: parallel-processing, computer-science, ram, python-xarray

I have many xarray files which I want to concatenate on Time.
Each file is around 37GB in size.

```
Each file read-in was done using the open_mfdatasets

ds20_power = xr.open_mfdataset(filepaths[220:], concat_dim='Time', combine='nested', engine='zarr')

datasets=[ds_power, ds2_power, ds3_power, ds4_power,ds5_power, ds6_power, ds7_power,
ds8_power, ds9_power, ds10_power, ds11_power, ds12_power, ds13_power, ds14_power, 
ds16_power, ds17_power, ds18_power, ds19_power, ds20_power]

power_dataset=  xr.concat(datasets, dim="Time")
```

How would I concatenate all the files together (20 in total) so that I have a single file stacked by Time with my RAM limitations (around 300GB)? And if there is a more optimum way to save this large file to decrease the read-in time for further analysis

Answer (score 0):

You could use the zarr-backend of xarray which has and append mode in `to_zarr()`.
[Here is the documentation from xarray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/io.html?appending-to-existing-zarr-stores=#modifying-existing-zarr-stores) which includes a simple example. You can modify this example by individually opening your netcdfs and appending it to the zarr-archive.